# WebBrowser looping url from txt file...

Tags: vb.net

I have one WebBrowser in my project that read info from a txt file... (just 1 line)... But everytime that I open the program, the browser is reloading all the time (like a loop) the url located at url.txt here's the code:

```
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim url As String = "url.txt"
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(url)
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(objReader.ReadLine)
        objReader.Close()
End Sub
```

I'll be thankful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the event handler in which you are loading the URL.  Right now you are doing it when the WebBrowser completes loading a document.  So every time it finishes loading, it will do it again.  I suspect you really want to do it when the form loads, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles Form1.Load
    Dim url As String = "url.txt"
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(url)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(objReader.ReadLine)
    objReader.Close()
End Sub
```